# Is there a way to use Select Case with Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use worksheet change to perform functions over 2 separate ranges on the same sheet. So far I have something along the lines of

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case ActiveCell.Address
Case "G1"
    ' Only proceed with Effects if the Effect dropdown changes
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim KeyEffects As Range, EffectCell As Range
    Set KeyEffects = Me.Range("Q32:BS32")


    ' Unhide all columns by default
    KeyEffects.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    If Me.Range("G1").Value <> "All" Then
        For Each EffectCell In KeyEffects
            If EffectCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> _
            Me.Range("G1").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex Then
                EffectCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf Me.Range("G1") = "All" Then
        KeyEffects.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    MsgBox "Working."

Case "D1"
    ' Only proceed with Causes if the Cause dropdown changes
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim KeyCauses As Range, CauseCell As Range
    Set KeyCauses = Me.Range("A34:A105")


    ' Unhide all columns by default
    KeyCauses.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    If Me.Range("D1").Value <> "All" Then
        For Each CauseCell In KeyCauses
            If CauseCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> _
            Me.Range("D1").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex Then
                CauseCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf Me.Range("D1") = "All" Then
        KeyCauses.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    MsgBox "Working."
End Select
MsgBox "Not Working."

End Sub
```

But I have yet to get a working message; am I doing something wrong with my Select Case statement? This is my first time trying to work with the Change Event handler and also using Select Case.
Thanks!

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the start of the select case and look at the value of `ActiveCell.Address` when it runs - is that what you expect?

Comment: 1.  Use `Target` not `ActiveCell`. 2 Remember that `.Address` by default will return an absolute reference: `$G$1`.

Comment: Yeah, changing the cases to include the dollar signs was all that was needed to fix it. Feel kind of dumb for not thinking to check what was being returned by the Address statement lol thank you both for pointing that out.

Comment: You may also want to test what happens when `Target` is a range of multiple cells instead of just one cell.